# Queued mail stuck for a while on exchange 2010 in coexistence with exchange 2016

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016

The emails are queued for approximately 2 hours and then it works for an hour, sending everything that is in queue. Repeat loop all the time.Each server is independent, there is no DAG.

They are only the email accounts in Ex2016 that remain in queue in Ex2010. The accounts in Ex2010 work without any problem.

With the following command I see the following error.

```
Get-Queue | FL Identity,LastError,MessageCount,NextHopDomain,Status
```

Error message:

```
Identity      : mail-Ex2010\151693
LastError     : 451 4.4.0 Primary target IP address responded with: "421 4.2.1 Unable to connect." Attempted failover to alternate host, but that did not succeed.
                Either there are no alternate hosts, or delivery failed to all alternate hosts.
MessageCount  : 50
NextHopDomain : hub version 15
Status        : Retry
```

The following points were reviewed:

```
DNS
rDNS
nslookup
Blacklist
FQDN
Antivirus
Firewall
Analyzing SMTP Logs
Restar service MsExchangeTransport
Recreate default receive connectors in Exchange Server
```

Register MX:

```
mx     server
5      mail-Ex2010
10     mail-Ex2016
```

I am suspecting that the priorities of the email servers are not working, I don't know how to test if the priorities are working.

Comment: Can you run the Test-Mailflow powershell command `Test-Mailflow -Identity <Exchange2010Server>`. Also check your send connectors if they are correct.

Comment: Exchange servers in coexistence don't use MX or PTR records or blocklists to deliver email between them.

Comment: >The emails are queued for approximately 2 hours and then it works for an hour, sending everything that is in queue - If it is actually working, will it be bandwidth or firewall?

Comment: I already checked @Kael , but thinking I shouldn't have the same problem in Ex2010. When I perform a [Microsoft Test input](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/InboundSMTP/input), it arrives instantly without problem. I deleted the SMTP that I created and left everything as default and when I restarted the MsEchangeTransport in Ex2010 it emptied all the queue it had.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion **@Turdie**.

During the hour that it works it works without problem. but during the two hours that the emails in queue accumulate, an error appears.

```
Test-Mailflow -Identity mail-Ex2010 -TargetEmailAddress User2016@gravetal.com.bo

RunspaceId         : 820a091c-c090-435d-8ae9-d8b07c7c64cd
TestMailflowResult : *ERROR*
MessageLatencyTime : 00:00:00
IsRemoteTest       : True
Identity           :
IsValid            : True
ObjectState        : New
```

---

```
Test-Mailflow -Identity mail-Ex2010 -TargetEmailAddress User2016@gravetal.com.bo

RunspaceId         : 98fed513-43b5-4398-8efb-48a61dc5e3ee
TestMailflowResult : Correcto
MessageLatencyTime : 00:00:03.3890779
IsRemoteTest       : True
Identity           :
IsValid            : True
ObjectState        : New
```

query **@joeqwerty**, the configuration of migration to coexistence of the mail server is not the same. I can put the mx records at the same priority without having a load balancer.

Then I have a question, the emails I send from Gmail to the Ex2016 user account first go to 2010 and get stuck in its queue and after several 2-hour retries it only arrives at 2016.
But from 2016 I sent without problem to 2010 and to gmail etc.